# Compute the last (decimal) digit of x1 ^ (x2 ^ (x3 ^ (... ^ xn)))

Tags: python, math, exponent

I need to find the unit digit of `x1 ^ (x2 ^ (x3 ^ (... ^ xn)))` from integers passed into the function as a list.
For example the input `[3, 4, 2]` would return `1` because `3 ^ (4 ^ 2) = 3 ^ 16 = 43046721` the last digit of which is 1. 
The function needs to be efficient as possible because obviously trying to calculate `767456 ^ 981242` is not very quick.

I have tried a few methods but I think the best way to solve this is using sequences. For example any number ending in a `1`, when raised to a power, will always end in `1`. For `2`, the resulting number will end in either `2, 4, 6 or 8`. 
If a number is raised to a power, the last digit of the resulting number will follow a pattern based on the last digit of the exponent:

1: Sequence is 1

2: Sequence is 2, 4, 8, 6

3: Sequence is 3, 9, 7, 1

4: Sequence is 4, 6

5: Sequence is 5

6: Sequence is 6

7: Sequence is 7, 9, 3, 1

8: Sequence is 8, 4, 2, 6

9: Sequence is 9, 1

0: Sequence is 0

I think the easiest way to calculate the overall last digit is to work backwards through the list and calculate the last digit of each calculation one at a time until I get back to the start but I am not sure how to do this?
If anyone could help or suggest another method that is equally or more efficient than that would be appreciated.

I have this code so far but it does not work for very large numbers

```
def last_digit(lst):
    if lst == []:
        return 1

    total = lst[len(lst)-2] ** lst[len(lst)-1]
    for n in reversed(range(len(lst)-2)):
        total = pow(lst[n], total)

    return total%10
```

Edit: `0 ^ 0` should be assumed to be `1`

Comment: @MattTimmermans that's javascript. I don't know how to replicate that in python

Comment: You have listed out those sequences quite nicely. Why don't you try fleshing out your solution to actually make use of them? Look for alternative or optimal solutions after you exhaust all your ideas, the sequences is a good start. Ask yourself how you'd be able to use those in your logic somehow instead.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh not meaning to be rude or anything, but the code I copied was a much earlier attempt and as I stated in my question I have no idea how I can use the sequences to keep looping through o find the correct answer

Comment: Don't worry, you're all good. I suppose in that case, one hint i can give is this: given starting number as, say 8, and given a power of 5, what result do you get? what about 9? and say 13? Do you see a pattern?

Comment: Would I need to sort through the list backwards, and for each pair of numbers, divide the exponent by the number of integers in the sequence for the last digit. This would show me what the last number of that calculation would be. Then replace those two items in the list with my new digit and carry on?

Comment: forwards would be the way to go.

Comment: Ok I'll give that a go

Comment: Apropo of nothing, if you're working this problem for recreation, you may want to check out https://projecteuler.net/ It's a site of several hundred recreational math problems that mostly require programming to solve.

Comment: @Van cheers mate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

x^n = x^(n%4) because the last digit always has a period of 4.

```
x  ^2  ^3  ^4  ^5

1   1   1   1   1
2   4   8   6   2
3   9   7   1   3
4   6   4   6   4
5   5   5   5   5
6   6   6   6   6
7   9   3   1   7
8   4   2   6   8
9   1   9   1   9
```

As you can see, all 9 digits have a period of 4 so we can use %4 to make calculations easier.

There's also a pattern if we do this %4.

```
x  ^0  ^1  ^2  ^3  ^4  ^5  ^6  ^7  ^8  ^9
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
2   1   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   1   3   1   3   1   3   1   3   1   3
4   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1    (all %4)
6   1   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7   1   3   1   3   1   3   1   3   1   3
8   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

As shown, there is a pattern for each x when n>1. Therefore, you can see that (x^n)%4 = (x^(n+4k))%4 when n>1. We can then prevent the issues that arises from n=0 and n=1 by adding 4 to n. This is because, if (x^n)%4 = (x^(n+4k))%4, then (x^n)%4 = (x^(n%4+4))%4 as well.

```
powers = [3, 9, 7, 1]

lastDigit = 1

for i in range(len(powers) - 1, -1, -1):
    if lastDigit == 0:
        lastDigit = 1
    elif lastDigit == 1:
        lastDigit = powers[i]
    else:
        lastDigit = powers[i]**(lastDigit%4+4)

print(lastDigit%10)
```

Comment: `[7, 6, 21]` did not work for me. I got `49` returned and not `1`

Comment: @HarryDay Are you sure it's meant to return 1? I've worked it out to return 9 (which it does now.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is

Comment: @HarryDay Ah yes you're right. It should be solved now.

Comment: Brilliant cheers mate

Comment: Your analysis is flawed; while it is true that `a^b^c^d^...z % 10 = a^(b^c^d^...z % 4) % 10`, that doesn't mean that `b^c^d^...z % 4 = b^(c^d^...z % 4) % 4`. Your code happens to work anyway, because the periods for `% 4` are almost compatible with the periods for `% 10` and the incompatibilities are handled by your ad-hoc special cases, but the analysis you have isn't enough to show that it works.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for the comment. I've added some more analysis. I think it's correct but I'm not 100%. (I'm in high school so don't have a lot of knowledge in this type of maths.)

Answer (score 2):

This is more math than programming. Notice that all the sequences you listed has length either 1, 2, or 4. More precisely, `x^4` always ends with either `0, 1, 5, 6`, as does `x^(4k)`. So if you know `x^(m mod 4) mod 10`, you know `x^m mod 10`.

Now, to compute `x2^(x3^(...^xn)) mod 4`. The story is very similar, `x^2 mod 4` is ether `0` if `x=2k` or `1` if `x=2k+1` (why?). So

1. is 0 if x2 == 0
2. is 1 if x2 > 0 and x3 == 0
3. if `x2` is even, then it is either `2` or `0` with `2` occurs only when `x2 mod 4 == 2 and (x3==1 or (any x4,...xn == 0) )`.
4. if `x2` is odd, then `x2^2 mod 4 == 1`, so we get `1` if `x3` is even else `x2 mod 4`.

Enough math, let's talk coding. There might be corner cases that I haven't cover, but it's should work for most cases.

```
def last_digit(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return 1

    x = lst[0] % 10
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return x

    # these number never change
    if x in [0,1,5,6]:
        return x

    # now we care for x[1] ^ 4:
    x1 = x[1] % 4

    # only x[0] and x[1]
    if len(lst) == 2 or x1==0:
        return x[0] ** x1 % 10

    # now that x[2] comes to the picture
    if x1 % 2: # == 1
        x1_pow_x2 = x1 if (x[2]%2) else 1
    else: 
        x1_pow_x2 = 2 if (x1==2 and x[2]%2 == 1) else 0

    # we almost done:
    ret = x ** x1_pow_x2 % 10

    # now, there's a catch here, if x[1]^(x[2]^...^x[n-1]) >= 4, 
    # we need to multiply ret with the last digit of x ** 4
    if x[1] >=4 or (x[1] > 1 and x[2] > 1):
        ret = (ret * x**4) % 10

    return ret
```

Comment: Could you explain this a bit more for me please as I don't understand?

Comment: @HarryDay see edited for more details

Comment: So how can I use that to create a function that gives me the correct result?

Comment: I guess this is due https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem , which because of some luck is applicable here. Note that `phi(10)=4` and `phi(4)=2`.

Comment: The sequences can be any length.

Comment: @dyukha exactly, I didn't want to include Euler's here though

Comment: `x2^(x3^(...^xn)) mod 4` is only `2` if `x2 mod 4 == 2` and `x3^(...^xn) == 1`. `x3` being odd isn't enough. Also, some of this analysis isn't valid when an exponent is 0.

Comment: @user2357112 Good catches.

Comment: I think you got the mechanics of 0 in an exponentiation a bit mixed up - `0^n == 0` for any positive integer `n`, but `n^0 == 1` for any nonnegative integer `n`. Thus, "(any x4,...xn == 0)" isn't enough to make `x4^(...^xn) == 0`.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks. Darn, this is too many corner cases (at least in my approach), will fix it later today.

Answer (score 0):

Working off of your sequences idea and fleshing it out, you'd want to create a dictionary that can map all relevant sequences.

```
mapping = {}
for i in range(1, 10):
    mapping[i] = [i]
    last_digit = i
    while True:
        last_digit *= i
        last_digit = last_digit%10
        if last_digit in mapping[i]:
            break
        else:
            mapping[i].append(last_digit)

print(mapping)
```

This produces Output: mapping

```
{1: [1],
 2: [2, 4, 8, 6],
 3: [3, 9, 7, 1],
 4: [4, 6],
 5: [5],
 6: [6],
 7: [7, 9, 3, 1],
 8: [8, 4, 2, 6],
 9: [9, 1]}
```

Now the real logic can start, The key takeaway is that the pattern repeats itself after the sequence is completed. So, it does not matter how big the power is, if you just use a modulo and figure out which position of the sequence it should occupy.

```
def last_digit_func(lst, mapping):
    if lst == []: #taken from OP
        return 1
    last_digit = lst[0] % 10
    if 0 in lst[1:]: #edge case 0 as a power
        return 1
    if last_digit == 0: #edge case 0 at start
        return last_digit

    for current_power in lst[1:]:
        if len(mapping[last_digit]) == 1:
            return last_digit
        ind = current_power % len(mapping[last_digit])
        ind -= 1 #zero indexing, but powers start from 1. 
        last_digit = mapping[last_digit][ind]
    return last_digit

test1 = [3, 4, 2]
print(last_digit_func(test1, mapping)) #prints 1
```

I verified this by calculating the powers in python.

```
test2 = [767456 , 981242]
print(last_digit_func(test2, mapping)) #prints 6
```

And i tried to verify this by running it in python....i now have instant regrets and my program is still trying to solve it out. Oh well :)

Comment: This almost works, there are a couple of cases where it's not working for me however. I forgot to say in the original post but `0 ^ 0` should be assumed as `1`

Comment: @HarryDay How about now, i didn't realise 0 would be allowed

Comment: @HarryDay Python automatically calculates `0^0` to be 1 so this shouldn't make much of a difference.

Comment: It would matter here because i never actually calculate a single power in the actual solution.

Comment: Your lines `if 0 in lst[1:]` doesn't solve the 0 problem. Take lst = [2, 2, 0, 2]. According to this line, it will return one but it should return 2^(2^(0^2)) = 2^(2^0) = 2^1 = 2

Comment: ah darn. you're right.

Comment: Yep that worked for `[0, 0]` but now `[0, 0, 0]` doesn't work