# Last digit of huge number Python

Tags: python, largenumber

I am trying to solve

```
x1 ^ (x2 ^ (x3 ^ (... ^ xn)))
```

where x1, x2, etc are numbers in the give list(`lst`) and the function should return last digit of result.

For example, if `lst = [3, 4, 5]`, it should return **1**.
Another example, if `lst = [499942, 898102, 846073]`, it should return **6**.

My code has passed sucessfully in the test with over 600 random lists from smallest to I think up to 6 digits long, but failed on these two lists:

```
[2, 2, 101, 2], [12, 30, 21]
```

**Function**:

```
def last_digit(lst):
    result = 1
    for num in reversed(lst):
        result = pow(num, result, 100)
    print(lst)
    return result%10
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compute the last (decimal) digit of x1 ^ (x2 ^ (x3 ^ (... ^ xn)))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53960629/compute-the-last-decimal-digit-of-x1-x2-x3-xn)

Comment: @bb1 The question seems to be solving same problem, but I had solution which worked on 598 random cases, but failed on 2. Now the answer from pixel explains what was wrong and it now passed 10 times 600 random tests - 6000 random tests. I believe community can benefit from my question and pixel's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track it can word for many cases but there's a small problem. see you are trying to calculate the last digit of a sequence of exponentiations. The problem is in how you're reducing intermediate results; You're currently reducing each intermediate result modulo 100, which might not always give you the correct last digit.

Here, you need to reduce each intermediate result modulo 10 instead of 100. Here's the modified version:

```
def last_digit(lst):
    if not lst:
        return 1  
    # Handle the case when the list is empty
    result = 1
    for num in reversed(lst):
        result = num ** (result if result < 4 else result % 4 + 4)
        # Reduce result modulo 4 and add 4 for optimization
    return result % 10
```

See in the loop firstly, we calculating the result modulo 4 for optimisation purposes and add 4. This step ensures that we are always working with positive exponents, which simplifies the calculation. Finally, we take the result modulo 10 to get the last digit.

It should handle your test cases correctly, including those that previously failed. Let me know if you need any other help.

Comment: I had to do another modification, as this only worked if result was more or equal to 4. ```result = num ** (result if result < 4 else result % 4 + 4)```, but still struggle to understand why it works now with modulo 4.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the modulo 4?

Comment: The 4 optimizes calculation by ensuring positive exponents and simplifying the modulo operation while preserving the accuracy of the last digit result. It' s a trick to handle large exponentiation sequences efficiently.

Comment: @pixel how would the exponent ever get negative, even without the "mod 4 optimization"?

Comment: to add more @pixel comment,  we use the property that the last digit of a number raised to a power repeats in `cycles of 4`. 
This means that for any number `x`, the last digit of `x^1` is the same as the last digit of `x^5, x^9, x^13,..` 
Similarly, the last digit of `x^2` is the same as the last digit of `x^6, x^10, x^14,...`
To use this prop, we can reduce the `exponent` to its `modulo 4` value if it's greater than 4.

Comment: *"you need to reduce each intermediate result modulo 10"* - Huh? That's not what your code does.

Comment: @Luatic, i think comment from `Sauron` dose answer your question, still in the context of calculating the last digit of exponentiation sequences, 4 reduces the range of possible exponents(taking all the exponents can lead to performance and memory issues). This doesn't affect the final result modulo 10 (the last digit).

Comment: `last_digit([2, 2])` returns `6`, that's not correct.

Comment: Yes, the code seems correct now (judging by my few tests). Still doesn't do what your text says, though. And the `if not lst:` is unnecessary.

Comment: @Sauron Those last digit cycles are relevant for the final exponentiation, since we then want the result modulo 10. But for the previous exponentiation, don't we rather need the outcome modulo 4 then? And for example 2^1 and 2^5 are *not* congruent modulo 4. I'm not convinced that using %4 is correct for any but the final exponentiation...

Comment: @KellyBundy the `4` is used as a constant in the expression, `result % 4 + 4` is done for `optimization` only
to reduce the value of `result modulo 4` before raising `num` to the `power` of result. By reducing result modulo 4,
the code effectively limits the `exponent` to a `maximum of 4`, which helps to avoid unnecessarily large calculations.
the addition of 4 is to ensure result is >=4

Comment: @KellyBundy For example, consider the number `7^5`. The last digit of `7^5` is the same as the last digit of `7^1`, which is `7`.
So, raising it to a power greater than 4 doesn't affect the last digit.

Comment: @Sauron None of that addresses what I said...

Comment: @bb1 m=1 and m=3 have the same parity, but `1**3%4=1` and `3**3%4=3`. So not quite just the parity.

Comment: But it seems while for example 2^1 and 2^5 are not congruent modulo 4, for example 2^2 and 2^6 are. And the reduction doesn't change exponents 1 and 5, the smallest change is from 8 to 4. And with such larger exponents, it indeed appears to be correct for the earlier exponentiations as well.